# Finding related SELECT clause in complex queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a very long and complex query. It includes a lot of subqueries. It's very diffcult to connect all those subqueries.

I have a `WHERE` clause that I can not assign to the corresponding `SELECT`.

Is there a tool to color highlight it to find the `SELECT` to this `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Could you use different types of joins instead of nested selections?

Answer (score 0):

I am personally not aware of a tool that highlight-matches `where` clauses with their associated `select`. Redgate SQL prompt does include certain highlighting features, but not for that specifically, and it's one of the most fully featured tools out there.

So I don't have an answer for your specific question (*"is there a tool..."*), but I think I can still help you out, but it's going to be much easier to provide this help in image form with some commentary, hence the answer rather than a comment..

Observe the wonders of formatting sql with vertical rivers!

[image: Observe the wonders of formatting sql with vertical rivers]

I have taken this screenshot with redgate sql prompt highlighting enabled, showing you something that it *does* highlight that might help a little bit: the subquery alias is highlighted at the point it is used. Obviously in this case that's pretty trivial because they're right next to each other, but you can imagine some larger query where that would actually be a useful indication.

But the main thing to notice is how easy it is to understand the structure of the queries when the `select` and `from` and `where`, etc, for each query and subquery, are aligned.

Yes, if you have many many levels of nesting, this takes up a bit more horizontal space. Of course you *can* do a similar thing with smaller indentation, but this is my personal style and I almost can't read anything else anymore. Besides, if the nesting is 3 or 4 levels deep something weird is going on, it's very rare to need that. In those cases you could always turn the subqueries into CTE's.